# Very simple excel vba macro. Specify value in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to essentially write some conditional formatting via macro. I want to assess the values in row E in my excel spreadsheet. For all values of 1, I want to change the entire row to be a different formatting. Here is what I have so far.

I have a COUNTA to count the number of Rows (displayed in H5). I have a COUNTIF(E:E,1) to count the number of rows with 1 as the value for that column (displayed in G5). Here's my code so far.

```
Sub Macro1()
'*****************
'Declare variables
'*****************
Dim xlWB, xlApp, xlSheet As Object
Dim xlTest As Worksheet
Dim RowNumber, TotalNumber, Count, i, j As Integer
Dim aCell, aRow As Excel.Range
Dim oInteger As Object
Dim oString As Object
'*****************
'Set variables
'*****************
i = 0
Range("G5").Select
Count = ActiveCell.Value
Range("H5").Select
TotalNumber = ActiveCell.Value
'*****************
'For loop to format
'*****************
For i = 2 To TotalNumber
    If ("E" & i = 1) Then
        MsgBox ("Doing something")
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I put in a MsgBox to find that ("E" & i) is showing up like 'E1', 'E2' etc. So that seems right. This; however, never matches the value of 1. I need to compare the value *in* that cell rather than the cell number. I don't know how to specify the selected cell's value.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need VBA for this?

Comment: No. It's just meant to help me learn how to code in VBA.

Comment: Pretty sure I just answered my own question. I just had to do 'Range(cell)' instead of 'Cell'. I can't post the code because I don't have enough rep but here is the snippet where it was breaking before:      If (Range("E" & i) = 1) Then
        MsgBox ("Doing something for row" & i)
    End If

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your **"E" & i** into a range to refer to the cell, else you just produce something like "E3", which will never be =1. Also, try not to use select, it slows your code down and isn't necessary.

```
Sub Macro1()
'*****************
'Declare variables
'*****************
Dim TotalNumber as Integer, Count as Integer, i as Integer
'*****************
'Set variables
'*****************
Count = Range("G5").Value
TotalNumber = Range("H5").Value
'*****************
'For loop to format
'*****************
For i = 2 To TotalNumber
    If (Range("E" & i).Value = 1) Then
        MsgBox ("Doing something")
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: worth noting that `rowNumber, TotalNumber, Count, i, aCell` are **all** `Variant` type. Only `j` is an `Integer`([converted to `Long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx)) and `aRow` is `Range` type